# What does "low profile" stand for, connected to hardware?

Tags: performance, hardware, hba

When it comes to hardware I often read something like "Apple Mac computers, and other **lower profile** ...."
For me it sounds like a better word for *low end segment hardware* but I am not sure about it. Google didn't help me well to answer this question.
Is there something more connected to it? I need it to fully understand some articles.
Term is used here for example: [HBA H240](http://www.uk.insight.com/en-gb/productinfo/storage-accessories/0003748315)

**Storage controller - plug-in card - low profile**

Comment: In the context of expansion cards it usually means "thin", sometimes it means "short". Why they can't just say "thin" or "short", I don't know. In your Apple Mac quote, it sounds like it's just the general non-IT meaning of "less well known".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have a few PCIe form factors:

You have different card and/or bracket heights:

```
FH - Full-height
HH - Half-height
```

And different card lengths:

```
FL - Full-length
HL - Half-lenth
```

"Low-profile" is synonymous with half-height, half-length (HHHL).

An HBA like the [HP H240](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04346303) is a half-length card that comes with full-height and half-height brackets, and can fit into either type of server slot. If using with a Server like an HP DL360p Gen8, this give you options on card placement.

Comment: AND: it is not lower end hardware. It is less HIGHT. Like 2U rack servers - too small for full height.

Comment: yep, I got that immediately :) , thanks for adding this info anyway

Comment: @RayofCommand This is specific to PCIe cards, per your question, but in general the term `low profile` can apply to a lot of different hardware and can mean more or less specific things in each case.  Sometimes it indicates a specific form factor, sometimes it just means somewhat vaguely smaller or thinner than typical.  Other examples are things like RAM (ie: VLP/ULP [Very Low Profile/Ultra Low Profile](http://www.virtium.com/embedded-ssd-and-industrial-memory-products/memory/vlp-very-low-profile/))

Answer (score 6):

In the linked example, it is a description of the interface card's "form factor" -- it's physical properties of size and shape.  It's about half the height of a regular PCI-E card.

Answer (score 6):

In a general sense "low profile" usually means roughly "thin" or to a lesser extent "small".

In the specific case of PCI and similar cards "low profile" means that the card is small enough to fit vertically in a 2U rackmount case or a desktop case of similar thickness.

Note that low profile slots require a different bracket (the metal piece that surronds the external connectors and joins card to case) from standard slots. A card with a low profile bracket won't fit in a standard slot. A card with a standard bracket can be inserted in a low profile slot but you won't be able to screw it in place or put the lid back on the case. Many low profile cards come with a pair of interchangable brackets to allow fitting in either standard or low profile slots but not all do.

Comment: Hmm, I usually see half-height slots with a horizontal orientation.

Comment: All the low profile slots i've seen have been with the card at right angles to the motherboard (so vertical in a desktop or rackmount setup, horizontal in a tower setup).

Comment: Nah... The HP DL300 series servers have horizontal half-height slots in their 1U and 2U servers (e.g. [DL380 G7](https://www.splusdirect.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/_/h/_hp-proliant-dl380-g7-barebone-with-motherboard-599038-001-293765-001-image-6.jpg))